# HTML5 Drop down with list

Tags: javascript, html, validation, w3c, html-select

im currently working on bringing a website up to date. Iv taken the code from one of the old pages and put it in the new website. It works but dosnt do so when when its being validated by w3c.

When I try and validate the code I get this error : Attribute rel not allowed on element option at this point.

The new website is being done in HTML5.

Is their an alternative way of doing this with HTML5?

Iv included some images to show what supposed to happen and a link to a page with the original code .

This images shows the drop down box

[image: Figure 1 . Options in the drop down box]

This image shows the result of selecting somthing

[image]

The code can be seen here if you right click an view source : [enter link description here](http://mk18.comoj.com/Stackoverflow.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the answer below was good , it didnt work in the end.

JS Fiddle here - [JS FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xUAs9/2/)

This code did however work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>


  <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js'></script>


<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
var select = $( '#dropdown' );

function showTab( name ) {
  name = '#' + name;
  $( 'div' ).not( name ).hide();
  $( name ).show();
}

select.change( function() {
  showTab( $( this ).val() );   
});

showTab( select.val() );
});//]]>  

</script>


</head>
<body>
   <form action="#">
                <p>
                <select id="dropdown" name="dropdown">
                    <option value="Pub-Chains" selected="selected"> Pub Chains </option>
                    <option value="Councils">Councils </option>
                    <option value="Property">Property </option>
                    <option value="Various">Various </option>
                    <option value="Universitys">Universitys </option>
                </select>
                </p>
            </form>


<div id="Pub-Chains">
Pub-Chains
</div>  

<div id="Councils">
Councils
</div>

<div id="Property">
Property
</div>

<div id="Various">
Various
</div>

</body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all remember to include `<!doctype html>` in your file to set the browser to "html5 standards mode"

For the options tags you haw should use the value attribute. like

```
<option value="acc">Accountants</option>
```

In your javascript file you can access this attribute in the same way as you access the rel attribute.

For the divs / the targets you should use id or class (or title) since these are all global attributes that can be assagned to any object in html5 ref: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_standardattributes.asp

Only use 'id' if the object is uniquely identified on your page, if you want to reference more object at a time consider using 'class'.

```
<div class="acc"> <!-- or 'div id="acc"' -->
<ul>
<li><a href="http://www.balmeraccountancy.co.uk/" target="_blank">Balmer Accountancy</a></li>

<li><a href="http://www.birchcooper.com/" target="_blank">BirchCooper</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.tearlecarver.co.uk/" target="_blank">Tearle &amp; Carver</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Hope this helps :-)

EDIT: almost complete code:

JAVASCRIPT:

```
var containerTag = 'DIV';

var compatible = (
    document.getElementById && document.getElementsByTagName && document.createElement
    &&
    !(navigator.userAgent.indexOf('MSIE 5') != -1 && navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Mac') != -1)
    );

if (compatible)
{
    //console.log('compatible');
    document.write('<style>.accessibility{display: none}</style>');
    var waitingRoom = document.createElement('div');
}

var hiddenFormFieldsPointers = new Object();

function prepareForm()
{
    //console.log('prepareForm');
    if (!compatible) return;
    var marker = document.createElement(containerTag);
    marker.style.display = 'none';

    var x = document.getElementsByTagName('select');
    for (var i=0;i<x.length;i++)
        addEvent(x[i],'change',showHideFields)

    var x = document.getElementsByTagName(containerTag);        //divs

    var hiddenFields = new Array;
    for (var i=0;i<x.length;i++)
    {
        if (x[i].getAttribute('class'))             //edit: class or id
        {

            var y = getAllFormFields(x[i]);
            x[i].nestedRels = new Array();
            for (var j=0;j<y.length;j++)
            {
                var rel = y[j].getAttribute('class');   //edit: class or id
                if (!rel || rel == 'none') continue;
                x[i].nestedRels.push(rel);
            }
            if (!x[i].nestedRels.length) x[i].nestedRels = null;
            hiddenFields.push(x[i]);
        }
    }

    while (hiddenFields.length)
    {
        var rel = hiddenFields[0].getAttribute('class');        //edit: class or id
        if (!hiddenFormFieldsPointers[rel])
            hiddenFormFieldsPointers[rel] = new Array();
        var relIndex = hiddenFormFieldsPointers[rel].length;
        hiddenFormFieldsPointers[rel][relIndex] = hiddenFields[0];
        var newMarker = marker.cloneNode(true);
        newMarker.id = rel + relIndex;
        hiddenFields[0].parentNode.replaceChild(newMarker,hiddenFields[0]);
        waitingRoom.appendChild(hiddenFields.shift());
    }

    setDefaults();
    addEvent(document,'click',showHideFields);
}

function setDefaults()
{
    //console.log('setDefaults');
    var y = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    for (var i=0;i<y.length;i++)
    {
        if (y[i].checked && y[i].getAttribute('value'))         //edit: value
            intoMainForm(y[i].getAttribute('value'))        //edit: value
    }

    var z = document.getElementsByTagName('select');
    for (var i=0;i<z.length;i++)
    {
        if (z[i].options[z[i].selectedIndex].getAttribute('value'))         //edit: value
            intoMainForm(z[i].options[z[i].selectedIndex].getAttribute('value'))    //edit: value
    }

}

function showHideFields(e)
{
    //console.log('showHideFields');
    if (typeof e == "undefined")
        e = window.event;
    var tg = e.target || e.srcElement;

    if (tg.nodeName == 'LABEL')
    {
        var relatedFieldName = tg.getAttribute('for') || tg.getAttribute('htmlFor');
        tg = document.getElementById(relatedFieldName);
    }

    if (
        !(tg.nodeName == 'SELECT' && e.type == 'change')
        &&
        !(tg.nodeName == 'INPUT' && tg.getAttribute('value'))           //edit: value
       ) return;

    var fieldsToBeInserted = tg.getAttribute('value');              //edit: value

    if (tg.type == 'checkbox')
    {
        if (tg.checked)
            intoMainForm(fieldsToBeInserted);
        else
            intoWaitingRoom(fieldsToBeInserted);
    }
    else if (tg.type == 'radio')
    {
        removeOthers(tg.form[tg.name],fieldsToBeInserted)
        intoMainForm(fieldsToBeInserted);
    }
    else if (tg.type == 'select-one')
    {
        fieldsToBeInserted = tg.options[tg.selectedIndex].getAttribute('value'); //edit: value
        removeOthers(tg.options,fieldsToBeInserted);
        intoMainForm(fieldsToBeInserted);
    }
}

function removeOthers(others,fieldsToBeInserted)
{
    //console.log('removeOthers');
    for (var i=0;i<others.length;i++)
    {
        var show = others[i].getAttribute('value');     //edit: value
        if (show == fieldsToBeInserted) continue;
        intoWaitingRoom(show);
    }
}

function intoWaitingRoom(relation)
{
    //console.log('intoWaitingRoom');
    if (relation == 'none') return;
    var Elements = hiddenFormFieldsPointers[relation];
    for (var i=0;i<Elements.length;i++)
    {
        waitingRoom.appendChild(Elements[i]);
        if (Elements[i].nestedRels)
            for (var j=0;j<Elements[i].nestedRels.length;j++)
                intoWaitingRoom(Elements[i].nestedRels[j]);
    }
}

function intoMainForm(relation)
{
    //console.log('intoMainForm');
    if (relation == 'none') return;
    var Elements = hiddenFormFieldsPointers[relation];
    for (var i=0;i<Elements.length;i++)
    {
        var insertPoint = document.getElementById(relation+i);
        insertPoint.parentNode.insertBefore(Elements[i],insertPoint);
        if (Elements[i].nestedRels)
        {
            var fields = getAllFormFields(Elements[i]);
            for (var j=0;j<fields.length;j++)
            {
                if (!fields[j].getAttribute('value')) continue;     //edit: value
                if (fields[j].checked || fields[j].selected) 
                    intoMainForm(fields[j].getAttribute('value'));  //edit: value
            }
        }
    }
}

function getAllFormFields(node)
{
    var allFormFields = new Array;
    var x = node.getElementsByTagName('input');
    for (var i=0;i<x.length;i++)
        allFormFields.push(x[i]);
    var y = node.getElementsByTagName('option');
    for (var i=0;i<y.length;i++)
        allFormFields.push(y[i]);
    return allFormFields;
}

/** ULTRA-SIMPLE EVENT ADDING **/

function addEvent(obj,type,fn)
{
    if (obj.addEventListener)
        obj.addEventListener(type,fn,false);
    else if (obj.attachEvent)
        obj.attachEvent("on"+type,fn);
}

addEvent(window,"load",prepareForm);


/** PUSH AND SHIFT FOR IE5 **/

function Array_push() {
    var A_p = 0
    for (A_p = 0; A_p < arguments.length; A_p++) {
        this[this.length] = arguments[A_p]
    }
    return this.length
}

if (typeof Array.prototype.push == "undefined") {
    Array.prototype.push = Array_push
}

function Array_shift() {
    var A_s = 0
    var response = this[0]
    for (A_s = 0; A_s < this.length-1; A_s++) {
        this[A_s] = this[A_s + 1]
    }
    this.length--
    return response
}

if (typeof Array.prototype.shift == "undefined") {
    Array.prototype.shift = Array_shift
}
```

HTML (I HAD TO REMOVE SOME DIVS TO BE WITHIN stackoverflow.com POSTING LIMIT!!):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>Stackoverflow Code Sample</title>

<link type="text/css" rel="StyleSheet" href="./Stackoverflow_files/mk18.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="./Stackoverflow_files/uf.js"></script>




</head>

<body class="twoColFixLtHdr">


<div id="container">
  <div id="mainContent">
    <h1 class="twoColFixLtHdr"><img width="480" height="29" src="http://mk18.comoj.com/Stackoverflow_files/weblinks.jpg" alt=""></h1>
<p></p>
<p>While advertising in MK18 we offer your company a free weblink. Select your choice by clicking the drop down and clicking the link to open.</p>
<form>
    <select>
 <option value="select">--- Click the drop down to select a weblink ---</option>
 <option value="acc">Accountants</option>
 <option value="acu">Acupuncture</option>
 <option value="adv">Advertising</option>
 <!-- //<option rel="aggt">Aggregates &amp; Topsoil</option>// --> 
 <option value="ant">Antiques</option>
 <option value="arcs">Architects &amp; Surveyors</option>

 <option value="artl">Artificial Lawns</option>
 <!-- //<option rel="artf">Art &amp; Framing</option>// --> 
 <option value="auc">Auctioneers</option>
 <option value="auts">Automotive Services</option>
 <option value="bat">Bathrooms</option>
 <option value="bea">Beauticians</option>
 <option value="boak">Boarding Kennels</option>
 <option value="bui">Builders</option>
 <option value="busn">Business Networking</option>
 <!-- //<option rel="buso">Business Opportunities</option>// --> 
 <option value="but">Butchers</option>
 <option value="carh">Car Hire</option>

 <option value="carho">Care Home</option>
 <option value="carj">Carpentry &amp; Joiners</option>

 <option value="carf">Carpets &amp; Flooring</option>

 <option value="cats">Catering Services</option>
 <!-- //<option rel="cars">Car Sales</option>// -->
 <option value="chas">Chauffeur Services</option>
 <option value="chis">Chimney Sweep</option>

 <option value="chir">Chiropractor</option>
 <!-- //<option rel="choc">Chocolatier</option>// -->
 <option value="cles">Cleaning Services</option>
 <option value="clor">Clothing Repairs &amp; Alterations</option>
 <option value="coms">Computer Services</option>
 <option value="corc">Corporate Clothing</option>
  <!-- //<option rel="cou">Counselling</option>// -->
 <option value="cra">Craftshop</option>
 <option value="curb">Curtains &amp; Blinds</option>
 <option value="cycs">Cycle Sales &amp; Repairs</option>
 <option value="deli">Delicatessen</option>
 <option value="denp">Dental Practice</option>
 <option value="dogg">Dog Grooming</option>
 <option value="dogt">Dog Trainer</option>
 <option value="dogw">Dog Walking &amp; Pet Sitting</option>

 <option value="dcw">Doors, Conservatories &amp; Windows</option>
 <option value="edut">Education</option>
  <!-- //<option rel="ele">Electricians</option>// -->
 <option value="estl">Estate Agents</option>
 <option value="eveh">Event Hire</option>

 <option value="fars">Farm Shop</option>
 <option value="fen">Fencing</option>
 <option value="finm">Financial &amp; Mortgage Services</option>
 <option value="fooh">Foot Health</option>
 <option value="fur">Furniture</option>
 <option value="garn">Garden Nursery</option>
  <!-- //<option rel="gars">Garden Sheds</option>// -->
 <option value="gla">Glazier</option>
 <option value="hai">Hairdresser</option>
 <option value="heaf">Health &amp; Fitness</option>
  <!-- //<option rel="hola">Holiday Apartments</option>// -->
 <option value="holh">Holistic Health</option>
 <option value="hyp">Hypnotherapy</option>
 <!-- //<option rel="inds">Independent Schools</option>// -->
 <!-- //<option rel="iros">Ironing Services</option>// -->
 <option value="kit">Kitchens</option>
 <option value="lang">Landscaping &amp; Gardening</option>
 <!-- //<option rel="lawt">Lawn Treatment</option>// -->
 <option value="lei">Leisure</option>

 <option value="let">Letting Agencies</option>
 <!-- //<option rel="lifc">Life Coach</option>// -->
 <option value="loce">Local Events &amp; Information</option>
 <option value="marh">Marquee Hire</option>
 <!-- //<option rel="nurs">Nursery Schools</option>// -->
 <option value="off">Office Services</option>

 <!-- //<option rel="oilt">Oil Tanks</option>// -->
 <option value="opt">Opticians</option>
 <option value="ost">Osteopath</option>
 <option value="paid">Painting &amp; Decorating</option>
 <option value="pesc">Pest Control</option>
 <option value="pluh">Plumbing &amp; Heating</option>
  <option value="prom">Property Maintenance</option>
 <!-- //<option rel="pros">Property Surveyor</option>// -->
 <option value="rec">Recruitment</option>
  <!-- //<option rel="recs">Record Shop</option>// -->
 <option value="res">Restaurants</option>
 <option value="roos">Roofing Services</option>
<!-- //<option rel="salm">Sales &amp; Marketing</option>// -->
 <option value="sol">Solicitors</option>
 <!-- //<option rel="sole">Solar Energy</option>// -->
 <option value="sty">Stylist</option>
 <!-- //<option rel="telb">Telephone &amp; Broadband</option>// -->
 <option value="tres">Tree Surgery</option>
 <option value="tvsa">TV Services &amp; Aerials</option>
 <option value="tyrs">Tyre Services</option>
  <!-- //<option rel="uph">Upholstery</option>// -->
 <option value="vet">Vets</option>
 <option value="vida">Video &amp; Audio Services</option>
 <option value="webd">Web Design</option>
 <option value="wilw">Will Writer</option>
    </select>
</form>
<div class="select">    
</div>
<div class="acc">
<ul>
<li><a href="http://www.balmeraccountancy.co.uk/" target="_blank">Balmer Accountancy</a></li>

<li><a href="http://www.birchcooper.com/" target="_blank">BirchCooper</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.tearlecarver.co.uk/" target="_blank">Tearle &amp; Carver</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="acu">
<ul>
<li><a href="http://www.joannesewell.co.uk/" target="_blank">Dr Joanne Sewell</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="adv">
<ul>
<li><a href="http://www.thebestof.co.uk/buckingham" target="_blank">Best of Buckingham</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.essentiallylocal.co.uk/" target="_blank">Essentially Local</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.hogstyend.co.uk/" target="_blank">Hogsty End</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.roundabouthere.co.uk/" target="_blank">Roundabout Here</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="aggt">
<ul>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="ant">
<ul>
<li><a href="http://www.adstockantiques.co.uk/" target="_blank">Adstock Antiques</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="arcs">
<ul>
<li><a href="http://www.ap-architect.com/" target="_blank">Andrew Pegley</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.georgesurveys.co.uk/" target="_blank">George Surveys Ltd</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="artf">
<ul>
<li><a href="http://www.theframing-centre.co.uk/" target="_blank">The Framing Centre</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<div class="artl">

<ul>

<li><a href="http://www.prestige-lawns.co.uk/" target="_blank">Prestige Lawns</a></li>

</ul>

</div>
<div class="auc">
<ul>
<li><a href="http://www.dickinsauctioneers.com/" target="_blank">Dickens Auctioneers</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="auts">
<ul>
<li><a href="http://www.chipsaway.co.uk/" target="_blank">ChipsAway</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.spotoncolours.co.uk/" target="_blank">Spot on Colours</a></li>

<li><a href="http://www.vass-tech.co.uk/" target="_blank">Vass-Tech</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="bat">
<ul>
<li><a href="http://www.aspirationalinteriors.co.uk/" target="_blank">Aspirational Interiors</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.hatschek.co.uk/" target="_blank">Hatschek</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.moretonbathroomsandkitchens.co.uk/" target="_blank">Moreton Bathrooms</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="bea">
<ul>
<li><a href="http://www.harmonybeautytherapy.co.uk/" target="_blank">Harmony Beauty Therapy</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.taylormadetreatments.co.uk/" target="_blank">Taylor Made Treatments</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.thebeautyboxbuckingham.co.uk/" target="_blank">The Beauty Box</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.thebeautytherapycentre.co.uk/ "target="_blank">The Beauty Therapy Centre</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="boak">
<ul>

<li><a href="http://www.cayla.co.uk/" target="_blank">Cayla Country Club</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="bui">
<ul>  
<li><a href="http://www.listed-buildings.com/" target="_blank">Country Renovations</a></li>

<li><a href="http://www.homefixbms.webeden.co.uk/" target="_blank">Homefix</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="busn">
<ul>
<li><a href="http://www.bucks-fizz.biz/" target="_blank">Bucks Fizz</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.theathenanetwork.co.uk/lauracarrick" target="_blank">The Athena Network</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="buso">
<ul>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="but">
<ul>
<li><a href="http://www.padburymeats.co.uk/" target="_blank">Padbury Meats</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="carf">
<ul>
<li><a href="http://www.chemdrymiltonkeynes.co.uk/" target="_blank">ChemDry</a></li>  
<li><a href="http://www.mjharrisflooring.co.uk/" target="_blank">M J Harris Flooring</a></li> 
<li><a href="http://www.stainbusters.co.uk/" target="_blank">Stainbusters</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="carh">
<ul>
<li><a href="http://www.twoheartsweddingcars.co.uk/" target="_blank">Two Hearts Wedding Car Hire</a></li>
</ul>
</div>


</div>
<!--end of list -->                         <br>
        <div id="footer-spacer"></div>
<!-- end #mainContent -->
</div>
        <!-- This clearing element should immediately follow the #mainContent div in order to force the #container div to contain all child floats --><br class="clearfloat">

        <!-- end #footer -->

 </body></html>
<!-- Hosting24 Analytics Code -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://stats.hosting24.com/count.php"></script>
<!-- End Of Analytics Code -->
```

There might be some errors so do tests!!

Good luck :-)

UPDATED::

Change your function prepareForm to somthing like this::

```
function prepareForm()
{
    //console.log('prepareForm');
    if (!compatible) return;
    var marker = document.createElement(containerTag);
    marker.style.display = 'none';

    var x = document.getElementsByTagName('select');
    for (var i=0;i<x.length;i++)
        addEvent(x[i],'change',showHideFields)

    var should_hide = new Array;

    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < x[i].length; j++) {
            should_hide.push(x[i][j].getAttribute('value'));
        }
    }

    var x = document.getElementsByTagName(containerTag);        //divs


    //console.log(should_hide);


    var hiddenFields = new Array;
    for (var i=0;i<x.length;i++)
    {
        var classname = x[i].getAttribute('class');
        //if (x[i].getAttribute('class'))           //edit: class or id
        if (classname && should_hide.indexOf(classname) != -1)
        {

            var y = getAllFormFields(x[i]);
            x[i].nestedRels = new Array();
            for (var j=0;j<y.length;j++)
            {
                var rel = y[j].getAttribute('class');   //edit: class or id
                if (!rel || rel == 'none') continue;
                x[i].nestedRels.push(rel);
            }
            if (!x[i].nestedRels.length) x[i].nestedRels = null;
            hiddenFields.push(x[i]);
        }
    }

    while (hiddenFields.length)
    {
        var rel = hiddenFields[0].getAttribute('class');        //edit: class or id
        if (!hiddenFormFieldsPointers[rel])
            hiddenFormFieldsPointers[rel] = new Array();
        var relIndex = hiddenFormFieldsPointers[rel].length;
        hiddenFormFieldsPointers[rel][relIndex] = hiddenFields[0];
        var newMarker = marker.cloneNode(true);
        newMarker.id = rel + relIndex;
        hiddenFields[0].parentNode.replaceChild(newMarker,hiddenFields[0]);
        waitingRoom.appendChild(hiddenFields.shift());
    }

    setDefaults();
    addEvent(document,'click',showHideFields);
}
```

Comment: That kind of helps , for the java script file what am i changing . The only javascrip file is uf.js , but I don't really know java script . This stuff is from the old website.

Comment: When i make your changes (minus the javascript) the page dosent work. Thats because of the javascrip , right?

Comment: You are right, the javascript is set to read the rel attributes of the `<option>` tags. You need to make the appropriate changes there. I will take a look and see if i can see what needs to be changed.

Comment: Hope this fixes your problems!

Comment: Okay , I have put the code on the new website and it dosent work. The page begins to load and then everything disappears. Take a look http://mk18.comoj.com/

Comment: You are right, the code now hides all divs that has a class. I added some code to the prepareForm() to only do this on divs whit class-names that correspond to the value of the option elements

Comment: Almost their , while that has fixed the page load problem , the drop down list no longer works. The are 10 options that constantly show and others dont.

Comment: You are correct! Thats beacuse there is no correspondent option-value for example the first link "The Framing Centre" has a class name of arf, and in your option list it is commented out `<!-- //<option rel="artf">Art &amp; Framing</option>// -->`. If you don't want to show them, comment out the divs.

Comment: Still not working . Iv commented out or removed dives that aren't required anymore. When something is selected in the drop down box , nothing happens.

Comment: Have you made any progress on this ?